# Lag storms while typing on iOS

Tags: ios

When I am typing, I get random 5-30 second pauses.  For instance I will type about 12 characters.  The first 10 characters will appear, then it's like time stops.  20 seconds later, those extra 2 characters will appear.  Then it's fine, and I get about 3 more seconds of typing before it "winks out" again for 10 seconds.

Most of the time, my iPad does not do this. *But when it does, it does it all day / for days.  What on earth is it doing?*

- Password screens are **immune** to this.
- Phone number entry fields are not.
- **Reset my dictionary** (which *had* 7 years of typos in it) did nothing.
- Clearing **Safari history and Website data** does not help.
- Double-home/**swipe-quit the app** does nothing (except lose your work).
- **Hard reboot**: Swipe-quitting all apps, starting a built-in app and holding down Home/On until the Apple logo appears; does nothing.
- I didn't always have a **bluetooth** keyboard. When I added one, that changed nothing.  It lags just the same if the keyboard is off, if Bluetooth is off, etc.  Bluetooth off+hard reboot changes nothing.
- Cleaned out **bookmarks** and reading list down from hundreds down to dozens - did not help.
- **Background App Refresh** off on all but Hangouts, FB Messenger, and Uber (because it would break them).
- **Storage**, 8.9GB free.
- About 12,000 **photos**.
- About 15,000 **emails**.
- I have **not reset my network** because I don't remember most of my WiFi passwords. However I am willing to turn on iCloud Keychain.

My iPad has done this sporadically for years through several major OS revisions.

It's an iPad 3 with iOS 9, **But here's the thing.  I'm willing to buy a new iPad, but what's the point?** Making the lags 1-6 seconds instead of 5-30 seconds still sucks. I'll do exactly the same things with the new iPad as the old one.